# Changing color of a JTable row runtime using another class and methods

Tags: java, swing, jtable

**Main class:**

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               new NewMDIApplication().setVisible(true); 
               new TestTable();
            }
        });
    }

 public JTable getMyJTable() {
      return jTable2;
   }
```

**Other class:**

```
package javaapplication9;

import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

 public class TestTable extends NewMDIApplication {
   public NewMDIApplication obj=new NewMDIApplication();
     public TestTable() {
                final DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) obj.getMyJTable().getModel();
                obj.getMyJTable().setModel(model);
                obj.getMyJTable().setDefaultRenderer(obj.getMyJTable().getClass(), new MyCellRenderer());
               }

    public class MyCellRenderer extends javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer {
            public java.awt.Component getTableCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTable table, java.lang.Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            final java.awt.Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            Object val = table.getValueAt(row, 1);
            String sval = val.toString();
            if (sval.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                cellComponent.setForeground(Color.black);
                cellComponent.setBackground(Color.red);

            } else {
                cellComponent.setBackground(Color.white);
                cellComponent.setForeground(Color.black);
            }
            if (isSelected) {
                cellComponent.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
                cellComponent.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
            }

            return cellComponent;
        }
    }
  }
```

This program is running.... but not showing any error. But when I edit some data of table through combo box, the color of table is not changing at runtime .

What would be a solution to this problem?

Comment: Post your [mcve] that demonatrates the problem. So create a simple table with hardcoded data and add the renderer to the table.

Answer (score 0):

There are two aspects to JTable cells: a renderer, and an editor. The renderer is used to display the cells, the editor is used when a cell is edited. You have the renderer done, but not the editor.

Supply the JTable with an editor that colors the edited cell the same way the renderer does. E.g. by way of the [`JTable.setDefaultEditor(Class<?> columnClass, TableCellEditor editor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setDefaultEditor-java.lang.Class-javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor-) method.

Comment: @Raj I suggest you edit your question, and add an [MCVE] to it.

Comment: Yes,sure....My query is very simple....I just want to edit a jtable column through a combo box and as soon as the value of column of particular row is changed , the background color of that row should be changed runtime.